# Shared drive between windows and ubuntu

Tags: drive

I have laptop which has HDD. I can use this HDD both in Ubuntu 13.10 and windows7. 

I have problem If I save some documents in UBUNTU, why I can not see that file in windows. Is there any valid reason behind this.
But vice versa is possible.

Comment: I couldn't comment, so I am adding it here. What is HDD filesystem? The problem is not seeing specific files or entire disk? If it is ext{2,3,4} filesystem then you can't see that in Windows. But Ubuntu can read Fat32/NTFS filesystems.

Answer (score 0):

One of the pains in having a dual-boot set-up with Windows and Ubuntu is suddenly realising you need to access a file on the other OSs partition.

In Ubuntu this is easy as Windows partitions can be mounted, read and written to out of the box – no configuration needed.

But the other way round? Well that’s a bit more complicated..

Ext2Explore
One tool I’ve long made use of to nab the odd file from my Linux partition when Windows-bound is  ‘ext2explore’.

The open-source ‘Ext2explore’ utility allows you to browse a Linux partition – be it Ext2, ext3 or ext4 – from within Windows, giving you the options to ‘save’ any files needed to a location of your choosing within Windows.

It’s not perfect, but if you’re forgetful or unable to access your Linux partition for whatever reason it’s a darn-well handy thing to have around.

Where to get it
Ext2Explore can be downloaded, for free, at sourceforge.net/projects/ext2read/.

How to run it
Ext2Read doesn’t come with a typical Windows installer. Instead you just unzip the archive, enter the folder and run the ‘ext2explore’ programme inside.

In Windows Vista and Windows 7 you will need to right click on this launcher and choose ‘Run as Administrator’.

Comment: This program isn't reliable on Windows 10